# Atribuir / alterar valor à variavel global no GO (golang)

Tags: funções, variáveis, golang

Estou tentando criar uma função que altere os valores das variaveis "monitoramentos" e "delay", porem quando tento utilizar a função alterarMonitoramento() ela apenas ignora o meu scanf e não deixa o usuario dar input em um valor, apenas da println direto tendo como resposta no terminal isso:

1- Iniciar Monitoramento

2- Exibir Logs

3- Alterar Configurações do Monitoramento

0- Sair do Programa

3

O comando escolhido foi: 3

Os sites serão testados 3 vezes a cada 5 segundos

Os sites serão testados 3 vezes a cada 5 segundos

```
var monitoramentos = 3
var delay int = 5

func main() {
    exibeIntroducao()
    for {
        exibeMenu()
        comando := lerComando()

        switch comando{
        case 1:
            iniciarMonitoramento()
        case 2:
            imprimeLogs()
        case 3:
            delay = alterarMonitoramento()
        case 0:
            fmt.Println("saindo do programa...")
            os.Exit(0)
        default:
            fmt.Println("Não reconheço esse comando")
            os.Exit(-1)
        }
    }
}
    func alterarMonitoramento() int{
    
    fmt.Println("Os sites serão testados", monitoramentos, "vezes a cada",  delay, "segundos")
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &delay)
    fmt.Println("Os sites serão testados", monitoramentos, "vezes a cada",  delay, "segundos")
    return delay
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Altere para:

```
fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &delay)
```

Assim o Scanf captura o seu enter. Pelo que li isso acontece no Windows, mas já havia sido resolvido. Porém como não uso Windows não tenho como verificar.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).